# Concourse CI get userId

Tags: continuous-integration, concourse

I was trying to get the last userId who committed and triggered a build in Concourse CI so that I can send it as part of slack notification. Can someone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Concourse does not save that information in an easily accessible way... you should write a task that runs `git log` in the correct directory and grabs the name of the last committer.